# Duda en SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, server, sql-server-management

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Soy nuevo y apenas estoy aprendiendo en el SQL Server Management Studio porque cuando cierro mi programa y después cuando lo vuelvo a abrir me salen estos errores y que puedo hacer para que solucionarlos?

Comment: Disculpen la ignorancia si es muy sencillo o obvio de solucionar

Answer (score 0):

Claro amigo, es porque la tabla ya está creada físicamente en la base de datos, eso significa que ya habías ejecutado ese Script (creando las tablas y probablemente insertando los datos con el insert into), entonces con eso no deberás volver a crear a la tabla e insertar la información cada vez que inicies sesión en el SQL, porque ya está creado.

Si te diriges en la sección de la izquierda y seleccionas
Base de datos ---> CINE ---> TABLES

ahí veras todas las tablas físicas que contiene la base de datos y seguramente esté las tablas a las que haces referencias.
También puedes hacer un select * from a la tabla para ver la información de la tabla
Ej: Select * from PERSONAL

te sugiero estudiar la diferencia entre tablas físicas y tablas temporales

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu código intenta crear una base de datos que ya existe, por lo que el interpretador lo rechaza inmediatamente, y por eso te indica el error.

Puedes solucionarlo colocando la siguiente línea al inicio, justo antes del CREATE DATABASE.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS CINE;
```

De esta manera al ejecutar el código, el compilador revisará las bases de datos almacenadas y si alguna concuerda con el nombre 'CINE' la borrará. Y así se podrá crear la base de datos.

Comment: Y así es como se borra la información de las bases de datos. Lo mejor sería solo crear la base de datos cuando no exista,

Comment: @LuisCazares En este ejemplo crea la base, las tablas, y realiza inserciones. Si lo hace como dices, seguiría teniendo error, ya que no podría crear las tablas. Y aún si sólo creara las tablas cuando no existan, los Insert subsiguientes generarían duplicados

Comment: Para todo se pueden crear validaciones. La solución que mencionas es efectiva para una demostración, pero no para ambientes productivos.